# Webform - can accept zero payment

Tags: webform-civicrm, payment

I have set up a webform to take event registrations. A user can click through to the payment form without selecting an event and can click submit. This doesn't register them for the event, but I would like to stop this. Due to the way I have setup the form I cannot use required fields on event selection. The webform is pretty complex.

Ideally, I would remove the submit button on the payment page unless the amount is greater than $0. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you can not use required fields on Event selection?

Comment: A user can select to attend 1 or 2 days (using radio buttons).  I have set these up at different events within civievent. Users can also select to attend a dinner (checkbox). Users are not required to attend 1 or 2 days, or the dinner.

Comment: How about making it one field with all events - checkboxes - and required (so they must check at least one checkbox but could do 1 day + dinner; or 2 days no dinner, etc?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that a user could book 1 day and both days? That wouldn't be great.

Comment: Not if you make your events day 1, day 2, dinner day 1, dinner day 2.

Comment: Thanks Karin. Good idea. I've already setup the webform with complex rules. But the next time I'll it up like this.

Comment: You're welcome - glad you got things working!